# $base_url variable in settings.php is not being read. How do i set this variable?

Tags: migrations

On my laptop I recently moved my Drupal sites from Acquia Dev Desktop server to a standard MAMP setup. Problem is the root dir folder isn't being read. The root dir folder name would be, by default part of the base url. For example, the mission page URL should be  `http://localhost:8888/mywebsite/mission`. But instead it's trying to load as `http://localhost:8888/mission`.

Since using Drupal I haven't had to once set a base url variable. In the settings.php file I found a variable for this which I uncommented and set. On line 282 in the settings file it now reads as like so:

```
$base_url = 'http://localhost:8888/mywebsite';
```

but this is having no effect whatsoever.

How or where can this be set? Or is there something I should do within the MAMP set up?

Answer (score 1):

Add a virtual host to the web server and use the directory where Drupal is installed as its document root directory.

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/website"

    # Other directives
</VirtualHost>
```